# s3_direct_upload within a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, amazon-s3

I have a form for Item, it has fields for name, category, condition, etc. I also want user upload images directly to S3. I am using s3_direct_upload to do that. But this runs into the problem of having a form with in a form, because s3_direct_upload will generate a form POST to s3, and it is inside the Item form.
I know nested form is not allowed. But any workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this issue:

Can't nest file upload form into another form
https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload/issues/74

Looks like this gem may work as an alternative:

https://github.com/sheerun/s3_file_field

Answer (score 0):

You can move nested form out, trigger it by javascript